# Results from 2 tables with unique rows depending on field value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Table1 that is related to Table2 on table1id.

Table1

```
id, telephone, name
1, 5555555555, joe smith
2, 5555555556, jack j
3, 5555555557, h. guy
```

Table2

```
id, table1id, street, status
1, 1, 1234 A street, GOOD
2, 2, 888 B street, BAD
3, 2, 54 A street, UNKNOWN
4, 3, 7th ave, BAD
5, 3, 1212 A street, suite 2, GOOD
6, 3, 5678 B street, BAD
```

The possible values for Table2.status are GOOD, BAD, and UNKNOWN

I'm looking for a query that returns distinct Table1.telephone and name depending on Table2.status.  So, if table2.status is GOOD, then result.active = yes, otherwise result.active = no

```
table1.id, telephone, name, street, active
1, 5555555555, joe smith, 1234 A street, yes
2, 5555555556, jack j, 888 B street, no
5, 5555555557, h. guy, 1212 A street, yes
```

UPDATED:  Fixed results

Comment: Where do address1 and two come from? They are now shown in your table examples

Comment: I can see a flaw in my thinking.  See the second row in the results.  The address if the record is BAD or UNKNOWN could any in the list.  I would have to give an order to GOOD, BAD or UNKNOWN I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the sample answer you have posted it seems like you do not want to include the rows from table 2 where same table1ID is happen to be with more than one Table2ID. for example Table1ID 3 is not in your result set.

based on that assumption this

```
    SELECT t1.id, t1.telephone, t1.NAME,t2.address1,t2.address2
            , CASE 
                    WHEN t2.STATUS = 'GOOD' THEN 'Yes'
                    Else 'No'
            END AS Active
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.id=t2.Table1ID
        AND t1.ID IN
    (
        SELECT TableID1
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY TableID1
        HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT ID) =1)
    )
```

Comment: Yes, no duplicates of table1.telephone and table1.name for multiple addresses in table2.  I'm getting the error: 'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.' when I try this answer.

Comment: I take that back.  I transposed the real life query from your answer incorrectly.  This works!  Thank you.

Comment: oh does that mean you still need atleast one of them? because in your result you eliminated table1ID =3 completly. but if you want to include then which one to pick ? in the given example Table1ID=3 has three instances and two of them has different value of STATUS. does picking any first one will work for you ?

Comment: What I decided was that I just needed result.active in my real life query, so I eliminated the address information (address1, address2, street) from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
select distinct t1.id, 
t1.telephone, 
t1.name, 
t2.street, 
case when t2.status = 'GOOD' then 'Yes'
     when t2.status = 'BAD' then 'No'
     else 'No' as active
end
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.table1id = t1.id
```

Comment: I'm getting duplicate rows of table1.telephone and table1.name for each address record in table2 with this answer.